# Is there any book or online tutorial for Scala DSL?

Tags: scala, dsl

I read  this one for DSL scala http://camel.apache.org/scala-dsl-getting-started.html. It doesn't help much for me. I want more details. Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is Debashish Gnosh book *[DSLs in action](http://www.manning.com/ghosh/)*. It isn't focused entirely on Scala, but has a good section on DSL developemnt using Scala. Generally this would be enough for starter knowledge, for deeper experience I would look at either ScalaTest or Specs source code.

Comment: I agree, _DSLs in Action_ is perhaps the best reference to dive into Scala DSLs. If you prefer an online option, you can read this [chapter](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/DomainSpecificLanguages.html) from _Programming Scala_. However, none of them cover metaprogramming techniques, that is to say, macros and reflection, so I encourage you to read the official [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) on those topics. It's amazing to see the flexibility that this new capabilities provide to Scala Internal DSLs.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of research ongoing in this area, especially regarding high-performing Scala DSLs. Look at:

- [Lightweight Modular Staging](http://scala-lms.github.io/)
- [Delite](http://stanford-ppl.github.io/Delite/)

Answer (score 1):

I've published [an article](https://dzone.com/articles/building-regular-dsls-in-scala) about building regular DSLs in Scala.

A short overview: most-likely the DSL you're trying to build belongs to a class of regular languages. If so, you can model this DSL with a finite state machine. The article contains a step-by-step manual how to transform that FSM to Scala code.